# c# Objeto en uso y Threads

Tags: c#

llevo varios días peleándome con un problema de

1. Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de
   enumeración.
2. Objeto en uso
3. no se puede acceder al objeto desechado

Tengo el siguiente código en el Form principal (que modifica un objeto GMAPControler del form) :

```
    // RE-DRAW MAP
    public void reloadMapOverlay(GMapOverlay overlay)
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(overlay)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("reloadMapOverlay: {0}", e);
            this.setError("reloadMapOverlay: " + e);
        }
    }
```

y en otra clase (Map_Custom.cs) llamo a la anterior función:

```
    addRoute(){
                            Console.WriteLine("Route");
            route.Points.Add(coords.get_position());
            overlay.Routes.Add(route);
            mainForm.reloadMapOverlay(overlay);}
```

(addRoute se llama mediante un thread:

```
                  Thread addRoute = new Thread(new ThreadStart(map.addRoute));
                    addRoute.IsBackground = true;
                    addRoute.Start();
```

)

- Los errores me salta en el objeto overlay.

pd: haciendo pruebas, si en

```
 Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(overlay)));
```

pongo

```
 Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(new GMapOverlay("A"))));
```

no tengo fallos, pero claro, la cosa es pasarle un overlay con datos y no crear uno nuevo cada vez.

un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta que el procedimiento es asincronico es muy probable que cuando inicia el thread, el objeto ya no este en memoria, la solucion es clonarlo .clone() o construir un nuevo objeto basado en el que se quiere pasar como parametro.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

Otra solucion es tener un atributo que contenga ese objeto que se quiere pasar, a nivel de clase que ejecute el thread.

Lo anterior es porque un objeto nunca se pasa por valor, en .NET los objetos siempre se pasan por referencia por ende si un objeto se crea a nivel de funcion y esa funcion termina, cuando el thread va a buscar ese apuntamiento en memoria, ya no encuentra nada.

Comment: hola Lcop, gracias por contestar. El error que me da es el siguiente:

Comment: reloadMapPosition: System.InvalidOperationException: Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración.
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
   en Car_Controller.View.FormMain.reloadMapPosition() en c:\Users\Gon\Desktop\Car_Controller\Car_Controller\Views\FormMain.cs:línea 903

Comment: estoy buscando como clonar el objeto overlay, pero no me da ninguna opción. Es un GMapOverlay

Comment: El clone es una interfaz, por ende debe ser implementada

Comment: Tiene que asegurarse que el objeto este vivo para cuando llega al thread

Answer (score 0):

```
reloadMapPosition: System.InvalidOperationException: Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración. en System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous) en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args) en System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method) en Car_Controller.View.FormMain.reloadMapPosition() en c:\Users\Gon\Desktop\Car_Controller\Car_Controller\Views\FormMain.cs:línea 903
```

Esto es un problema de concurrencia.

¿Dónde creas el objeto map? tiene toda la pinta de que lo estás modificando/eliminando de alguna forma antes de que acabe la ejecución del hilo addRoute.

Prueba una cosa, inserta un simple

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

justo después del

```
addRoute.Start();
```

Si con eso te funciona adecuadamente, entonces está pasandolo que yo te digo. La solución más sencilla que se me ocurre en este caso es pasarle una copia del objeto map, en vez de pasarle la referencia a map.addRoute.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola Roberto y compañía, gracias por vuestra ayuda, al final tras mucho tocar conseguí arreglar el fallo. Efectivamente es lo que comentas.

Comment: Nada, para eso estamos :)